# Reading .xml Excel files in Python

Tags: python, xml, excel

I've some .xml files generated by Excel that I've to read with Python. I looked for Python Excel libraries, but they doesn't seems to read .xml files. Parsing manually seems complicated. What do you suggest?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to export it from Excel to some intermediate format? E.g., CSV?

Comment: or you can use xml library to parse xml data. for more information: [pydocs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml)

Comment: I can't choose the file format. xml parsing adds complexity: I would use it only if needed.

Comment: if it's regular xml, then there are plenty of great xml parsing libs in python..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe plain xml parsing (lxml.etree) would work? http://lxml.de/tutorial.html